# Visual Studio 2017 / Xamarin fail to run app on iPhoneSimulator

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

** solved by trial and error, see comments **

Anyone who can help me troubleshoot the process of loading an iOS app into the XCode iPhoneSimulator?

Recently I set up the latest VS 2017 + Xamarin + XCode on my Mac Pro (MacOS 10.12.6 "Sierra"). I created a portable HelloWorld app with Xamarin, and it runs fine on the iPhoneSimulator, so everything is wired together correctly. I did also try a HelloWorld in XCode, it runs in the simulator too.

Today I loaded a sample app from GitHub, which is also a portable app supporting Android and iOS. After unloading the .Droid hive, I could successfully build it, no errors of any kind.

But if I try to run it in the iPhone simulator, the simulator starts, but then nothing happens any more, obvioulsly the app doesn't get executed, or an attempt to execute it is made, but fails silently. Other Xamarin apps appear on the iOS start screen, this one doesn't, it seems like it never reaches the simulator, or is rejected for some reason. System log shows nothing unusual. Usual steps to clean up the application and get an entirely new build (delete .obj and .bin and then rebuild all) have been tried, but no success.

Can anyone give me instructions ho I can do further troubleshooting? On Windows, I'd try to load the ready built apk into the simulator from a terminal window, sometimes this gives additional error infos, but on the Mac I have no idea how to accomplish this. What I can say though is that the build creates a ton of files in the debug directory (.exe, .dll, .pdb), but from ther I don't know how to proceed further.

The .Droid hive of the same application compiles and runs perfectly on my Windows host under the Android simulator.

Comment: Please check your Mac. Does it have enough storage?

Comment: It has plenty of storage, that's very likely not the problem. After all, any other Xamarin project I tried runs in the iPhone simulator --> there's very likely something wrong in the iOS part of the Xamarin project, but the build process fails to recognize it.

Comment: You may try to create a new blank forms project. Can its iOS part run on the simulator?

Comment: Please read my question. I have clearly mentioned that I can run *any* iOS project, except this one. Anyway, I was able to resolve the issue in the meantime by trial and error. Still wonder whether the emulator had provided any warning somewhere, which would have saved me hours of trial and error until I found the prioblen setting. I'll add a note to my original question.

Comment: I found the problem, the old project (from 2014) had the setting "iOS project -> Build -> iOS Build -> Supported architectures" set to "i386", changing this to "x86_64" or "x86_64 + i386" resolved the issue. In the aftermath I found an article at the Xamarin website explaining this. But I am still wondering whether there is a way to do proper diagnostics to find issues with the simulator, a logfile maybe or some console output, so I leave this question open for the moment.